# Is it possible to use Memory Stream how input file for FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, memorystream, sharpffmpeg

I'm trying to work with ffmpeg in a .NET application. Is it possible to use a memory stream **instead** `-i [string inputFilePath]` to get some frames for example? Many thanks for any answer.

Comment: `ffmpeg` can accept pipe as input.

Comment: But we cannot using pipes with files that requires seeking when encoding (e.g. mp4, mkv, etc)

Comment: Can you not use a format that can handle pipe?

Comment: No, because I need  work with all files. I tried to convert these files to .avi (with stream) but it doesn't work with pipes how input data +  mp4 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task will be good libvlc (https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp), VLC (as I guess) use ffmpeg back-end, that's why for many task with stream media input file VLC will be perfect solution. For example to take snapshots or playing different video/audio streams from input memory-stream file. If you want to use ffmpeg with some stream input files, you must use Pipes, but if file cannot converting into pipes (e.g. .mp4 or .mkv), you must work directly with some libs (such as libavcodec etc). Hope this answer will help someone with the same problem. Good Luck.